# "overestimates topoi" and research level

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, asking-questions, vote-to-close

I wonder now and then, why this question is still open

[Did Grothendieck overestimate topoi?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330087/did-grothendieck-overestimate-topoi)

Usually, MO's members tend to be very strict about what is and what isn't a good question.

> But why is this a good question?

D Clausen has clarified the controversial nature of the quote, regarding the content of the quote I really wonder if the OP has at least read RetS, where Grothendieck explains in detail why he thinks topos is a deep notion, and in fact a transformation of the very nature of space. It's ok If the Op doesn't agree with G's digression, but the question is not even a historical one.

Usually, we see questions of people that have not encountered an object in their research and they think that the object is unmotivated, or suggest a lack of imagination of the mathematician that creates it.

Topos theory now has a community, with international congresses and a wealth of publications and applications.

Why this question is research-level mathematics?

Comment: while I do think you can conclude from a closed question that it is not "research-level mathematics", I don't think the converse is true; In reference to your comment on the role of moderation: in most cases (spam is the exception) whether a question is closed or remains open is decided by the community, not by a moderator.

Comment: I am going to edit that, my aim is not to be controversial in that point.

Comment: I'll just add that on the [timeline of the post](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/330087/timeline) one can see whether it was in the close votes review queue and how many times. (In this specific case, it happened once.)